# Conditional update column B with modified value based on column A

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am facing a large table with data that got imported from a csv. However the delimiters in the csv where not sanitized, so the input data looked something like this:

```
alex@mail.com:Alex
dummy@mail.com;Bob
foo@bar.com:Foo
spam@yahoo.com;Spam
whatever@mail.com:Whatever
```

During the import : was defined as the delimiter, so each row with the delimiter ; was not imported properly. This resulted in a table structured like this:

```
| ID  | MAIL                | USER     |
|-- --|---------------------|----------|
| 1   | alex@mail.com       | ALEX     |
| 2   | dummy@mail.com;Bob  | NULL     |
| 3   | foo@bar.com         | Foo      |
| 4   | spam@yahoo.com;Spam | NULL     |
| 5   | whatever@mail.com   | Whatever |
```

As reimporting is no option I was thinking about manually sanitizing the data in the affected rows by using SQL queries. So I tried to combine SELECT and UPDATE statements by filtering rows WHERE USER IS NULL and update both columns with the correct value where applicable.

Comment: Hi @Es Ka thank you for your question, Can you please provide the code example you have been using and explain what not working (Note: Your general approach is good and this can definitely be achieved by an SQL query)

Answer (score 0):

What you need are string functions. Reading a bit, I find that Google BigQuery has STRPOS() and SUBSTR().

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#strpos

An update query to fix the situation you are describing looks like this:

```
update table_name set mail =SUBSTR(mail,1,STRPOS(mail,';')-1), user =SUBSTR(mail,STRPOS(mail,';')+1) where user is null
```

The idea here is to split mail in its two parts, the part before the ; and the part after. Hope this helps.